# Reversing a string without using pointers

Tags: c, string

I'm supposed to copy `char orig[]` to `char reversed[]` and reverse it. My function works but doesn't properly reset the string as evidenced by the fact that a blank string returns the prior test results. How can I fix this?

```
 void reverse(char orig[], char reversed[]) {
    int lastChar = strlen(orig) - 1;
    int lastCopy = lastChar;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lastChar; i++){

        reversed[lastCopy] = orig[i];
        reversed[i] = orig[lastCopy];
        lastCopy--;

        reversed[lastChar+1] = '\0';
    }

    return ;
}
```

This is what I get as output:

```
Test "software" (Pass, returns: erawtfos)
Test the empty string
Assertion failure
Have:   <erawtfos>
Expect: <>

Test a long string (Pass)
Test a simple palindrome (Pass)
4 assertions: 3 passed 1 failed
```

Comment: You forgot to add the NUL terminator in the target string.

Comment: Posting text, rather than pictures of text is more useful.

Comment: Fixed, my apologies!

Comment: You need to throw in a `reversed[lastChar+1] = '\0';` in there somewhere, and eliminate the `reversed[i] = temp;` line entirely. For that matter, why have the variable `temp` at all?

Comment: The blank test still fails after adding the NUL terminator. It contains `erawtfos` when it should contain nothing. Why does it not properly erase?

Comment: I guess originally it was an in-place reverse. clearly doesn't make sense now...

Comment: @N1ghtshade3: should work. post code. please tell me you haven't put that code *in* the loop.

Comment: @N1ghtshade3: any more questions? :D

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, Nope, just a general feeling of foolishness.

Comment: Your code has several problems, but it's failing the test because the line that puts the null terminator at the end of the result is inside the loop. When the input has zero length, the loop body never executes at all, so the result is a junk string.  I'll let you figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP problem: When the original string `orig` has length 0 or 1, the null character is never set in `reversed`.

Instead create a simple loop pulling 1 `char` at a time.

```
// As `orig` elements are not changed, good C style to make it `const`
void reverse(const char orig[], char reversed[]) {

  // use `size_t` as `int` may be too narrow
  size_t length = strlen(orig);

  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    reversed[i] = orig[length - i - 1];
  }

  reversed[i] = '\0';
}
```

If `orig` and `reversed` might overlap, a temporary copy is needed.

```
void reverse(const char orig[], char reversed[]) {
  size_t length = strlen(orig);
  char tmp[length+1];  // Add 1 because an array of size 0 is UB
  memcpy(tmp, orig, length);

  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    reversed[i] = tmp[length - i - 1];
  }

  reversed[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify:

```
void reverse(char orig[], char reversed[]) {
    int len = strlen(orig);
    int last = len - 1;

    reversed[len] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        reversed[last] = orig[i];
        last -= 1;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This causes the first character of the reversed (last of the original) to go missing

Answer (score -1):

you can use built in functions like string::rbegin(),string::rend()

in order to copy string reversely.

```
 string copy(orig.rbegin(),orig.rend());
```

don't forget to include < string.h >

Comment: The questions says `C` not `C++` and even for `C++`, `std::string` and co re found in `<string>` not the C `<string.h>`